# Creating something LIKE a workflow, but not as complicated

Tags: sharepoint-online

I'm REALLY new to Sharepoint. I'm looking to create a folder that employees of the company can upload documents to. These documents need to be approved by our manager. Once they are approved they are sent to a new folder to be processed. If they are not approved, a message will go to the uploader that more work needs to be done. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new SharePoint Designer workflow. Set workflow to start automatically on item create.

Add a custom action to Start Approval Process on current item. Select who the approver is.

Now you can add logic if Approved then move current item to another folder.
If rejected you can use Send Email Action to inform actual uploader.

[Video: Create an approval workflow in SharePoint Designer 2010](https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/Video-Create-an-approval-workflow-in-SharePoint-Designer-2010-d7497373-964f-4470-a7d3-aa25cc84c050)